# Headers interface for fetch API not working in specific POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, header, fetch

This Node.js code in a React-app doesn't work (fetch never resolves)

```
const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formBody,
    headers: headers
  };
```

However, if you don't use the Headers interface, the code works:

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formBody,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
  };
```

The example is from Express router where fetch returns an access token. I usually use the Headers interface and this specific case is the first time I have had problems. Is there a reason why I can't use the Headers interface in this case or is it a bug?

Comment: What is the error you encountered with?

Comment: Express sends "Service unavailable" - I catch the error like this: catch((err) => {
          if (err.status) {
            res.status(err.status).send(err.message);
          } else {
            res.status(500).send(err);
          }
        });

Comment: You can also update your post and this error to your question for better results.